# REST API Как разделить grant type password и client_credentials в запросах

Tags: php, yii2, api, rest

Всем привет.
Разбираюсь с REST API, помогите пожалуйста разобрать один момент.
Делаю на yii2, использую [эту](https://github.com/filsh/yii2-oauth2-server) библиотеку.

Авторизация на сайте будет для приложения и для клиента. Для приложения выдаю токен по запросы с `grant_type: client_credentials` , для пользователя `grant_type:password`

Допустим у меня в ресте есть 5 методов:

```
GET /users
GET /users/1
PUT /users/1
DELETE /users/1
POST /users/create
```

Логично предположить, что `GET /users` не должен быть доступен для пользователя, а только для приложения.

Как мне понять в каком случае я могу дать ответ, а где я должен ответить forbidden? Ведь в обоих случаях запросы будут приходить с access token.
Думал создавать для каждого клиента 2 приложения с разными client_id и client_secret (т.е. один будет для самого приложения, второй для пользователей приложения) и с помощью scopes разделять разрешенные маршруты.
Но так и не понял как обращаться со scope, как их привязать к rbac, как автоматически определять по scope разрешенные маршруты, а ведь еще у каждого пользователя в зависимости от его состояния могут быть разные права (например если заказ отменен, он не может его оплатить и выдавать этот scope клиенту не нужно). Вопросов стало только больше.

Подскажите, может я двигаюсь совсем не в том направлении? И как делать в этом случае правильно?
Если непонятно объяснил, напишите в комментарии - поправлю вопрос.

Comment: Пользователь у Вас авторизуется. Вы выдаете ему токен. Сохраните его в БД. Все запросы к Вашему API должны идти с указанием токена. Далее по токену получайте из БД пользователя и понимайте кто это у Вас и соответственно разруливайте права на методы.

Comment: у client_credentials нет пользователя. Это приложение, а не пользователь

Comment: Это понятно. Но `API` Вы пишете. Кто Вам мешает представить приложение просто-напросто еще одним пользователем. Лично у меня в `API` по приему оплат, что реальный пользователь входящий через сайт, что приложение под `Android` - все считаются пользователями. Единственное, что, в отличии от Вас, я их всех опознаю и разграничиваю в правах по выданным самоподписанным сертификатам. Это позволяет защититься от `bruteforce`-атак и попыток найти что-то `этакое` в `API` еще на стадии обращения к `URL` средствами веб-сервера. А в серьезных проектах я еще и требую подписывать сообщения сертификатом.

Comment: т.е. предлагаете отказаться от client_credentials и всегда использовать grant_type:password и уже юзера разграничить ролями?

Comment: Решать Вам. Полностью задачу знаете только Вы. Я вот не понимаю почему именно для `API` выбрана схема авторизации через `oAuth2`. Могу понять такой выбор для авторизации на сайте, но никак не для `API`.

Comment: разве есть альтернативы?

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/rest-authentication